# How can I shade sections of a JSXGraph board?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I have a [jsxgraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/index.html) board set up with a few simple lines, like this:

[image: my jsxgraph]

I want to shade portions of it, for example, the white area between the blue line and the dotted line. What's the best way to go about this? I've looked in [the API](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/index.html) but none of the provided elements jumped out at me, and I haven't seen any examples so far that do what I'm trying to do. Is the [Inequality](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/symbols/Inequality.html) element easily extendable to multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a polygon and hide the edges and vertices of the polygon. Here is an example:

```
    var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard("jxgbox", {
        boundingbox: [-1, 5, 5, -1],
        axis: true
    });

    var p1 = board.create('point', [2, 1]);
    var shade = board.create('polygon', [p1, [0,p1.Y()], [0,4]],
            {
                borders: {visible: false},
                vertices: {visible: false}
            }
        );
```

If you need to intersect the coordinate axes, you can access them with
`board.defaultAxes.x` and `board.defaultAxes.y`.