# How can I shade inside the curve using JSXgraph

Tags: javascript, function, math, jsxgraph

I'm currently trying to shade a quadratic inequality. For that I must be able to shade inside and/or outside of the determined curve. I have looked through [JSXgraph documentation](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/index.html) and I do not seem to see anything helpful to my problem.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821727/how-can-i-shade-sections-of-a-jsxgraph-board) does not apply to my scenario.

The current code to create the curve:

```
// Function y = ax^2+bx+c
function quadraticFunctionClassical(y, symbol, a, b, c, field, color) {
    var graph = board.create('functiongraph', [function (x) { return (a * Math.pow(x, 2) + (b * x) + c); }], { id: field, strokeColor: color, highlightStrokeColor: 'yellow', strokeWidth: 2 });
    graph.on('down', function (e, i) {
        showMaster(this.id);
    });
    graphMap.set(field, graph);
}
```

Any suggestions? I will e-transfer 100$ to the person who helps me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the inner of the graph should be filled one can use two inequality-elements like this, see https://jsfiddle.net/kvq0xmL6/ :

```
var graph = board.create('functiongraph', [
    function (x) { return (a.Value() * x * x + b.Value() * x + c.Value()); }
  ], { strokeColor: 'black', highlightStrokeColor: 'yellow', strokeWidth: 2});

var ineq_lower = board.create('inequality', [graph], {visible: false});
var ineq_upper = board.create('inequality', [graph], {inverse: true});
a.on('drag', function() {
  if (this.Value() >= 0.0) {
    ineq_lower.setAttribute({visible: false});
    ineq_upper.setAttribute({visible: true});
  } else {
    ineq_lower.setAttribute({visible: true});
    ineq_upper.setAttribute({visible: false});
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried implementing this to my project and I get the following error, `jsxgraphcore.js:70 Uncaught Error: JSXGraph: Can't create area with the given parents.
Possible parent types: [line], [function] at Object.t.createInequality [as inequality] (jsxgraphcore.js:70)`

Comment: I think I had a wrong version or a version with a bug. I changed the jsxgraphcore.js file with yours and it works! Do you have an email I can transfer the money ?

Comment: The problem with thiis approach is that it glitches, here is the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529008/how-to-fix-inequality-glitch-for-jsxgraph)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is not possible out-of-the-box in JSXGraph. But for specific function graphs it should be doable. The trick is to have a further graph which handles the shading.

For the case of the parabola we clone the points of the parabola to the shading curve and prepend and append further points such that the filled region is always below the curve. Here is the code:

```
var left = -5, right = 5, top = 5, bot = -5;
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [left, top, right, bot], axis:true
});

var a = board.create('slider', [[-4,4],[3,4],[-10,1,10]], {name:'a'});
var b = board.create('slider', [[-4,3.5],[3,3.5],[-10,1,10]], {name:'b'});
var c = board.create('slider', [[-4,3],[3,3],[-10,1,10]], {name:'c'});

var graph = board.create('functiongraph', [
    function (x) { return (a.Value() * x * x + b.Value() * x + c.Value()); }
  ], { strokeColor: 'black', highlightStrokeColor: 'yellow', strokeWidth: 2});

// Add a second curve for the filling
var g1 = board.create('curve', [[], []], 
  {fillColor: 'yellow', fillOpacity: 0.2});

// This is the update function for the second curve
g1.updateDataArray = function() {
  var i, le = graph.numberPoints;
  this.dataX = [];
  this.dataY = [];

  // Add the lower left corner of the board
  this.dataX.push(left);
  this.dataY.push(bot);
  if (graph.points[0].usrCoords[1] > left) {
    this.dataX.push(left);
    this.dataY.push(top);
  }
  // Add the points of the original curve
  for (i = 0; i < le; i++) { 
    this.dataX.push(graph.points[i].usrCoords[1]);
    this.dataY.push(graph.points[i].usrCoords[2]);
  }
  // Add the lower right corner of the board
  if (graph.points[le - 1].usrCoords[1] < right) {
    this.dataX.push(right);
    this.dataY.push(top);
  }
  this.dataX.push(right);
  this.dataY.push(bot);
};
// An update of the board is mandatory to show the filling immediately.
board.update();
```

See it in action at https://jsfiddle.net/7retmajL/ .

Comment: Are you able to shade the inner part of the curve ? JSXgraph has an [example](https://jsxgraph.org/docs/symbols/Inequality.html) in their documentation, but it doesn't seem to work. (The last example)